# how to mock an object that is used inside the tested method?

Tags: unit-testing, dialog, modal-dialog, moq

I am doing some tests to learn about how to mock methods that use dialog boxes. I have this classes:

My Interface, that is a wrapper for the MessageBox.

```
public interface IDialogoDummy
    {
        ResultadoDialogo dummy(string paramMensaje, string paramCaption, System.Windows.MessageBoxButton paramBotones, MessageBoxResult paramBotonPorDefecto);
    }
```

The class that implements my interface:

```
public class DialogoDummy : IDialogoDummy
    {
        //El método tiene que ser virtual para que moq pueda utilizarlo
        public virtual ResultadoDialogo dummy(string paramMensaje, string paramCaption, System.Windows.MessageBoxButton paramBotones, MessageBoxResult paramBotonPorDefecto)
        {
            MessageBoxResult resultado = System.Windows.MessageBox
                    .Show(paramMensaje,
                    paramCaption,
                    paramBotones,
                    MessageBoxImage.None,
                    paramBotonPorDefecto);

            if(resultado == MessageBoxResult.Cancel)
            {
                return ResultadoDialogo.Cancel;
            }
            else if(resultado == MessageBoxResult.No)
            {
                return ResultadoDialogo.No;
            }
            else if(resultado == MessageBoxResult.None)
            {
                return ResultadoDialogo.None;
            }
            else if(resultado == MessageBoxResult.OK)
            {
                return ResultadoDialogo.OK;
            }
            else if(resultado == MessageBoxResult.Yes)
            {
                return ResultadoDialogo.Yes;
            }
            else
            {
                return ResultadoDialogo.Unknown;
            }
        }
    }
```

And a class that use my method:

```
public class DialogoDummyMethods
    {
        //El método tiene que ser virtual para que moq pueda utilizarlo
        public int getInt()
        {
            IDialogoDummy miGestor = new DialogoDummy();
            ResultadoDialogo resultado = miGestor.dummy("OK es 0 y cancel es 1", "Test", MessageBoxButton.OKCancel, MessageBoxResult.Cancel);
            int intResultado;
            if (resultado == ResultadoDialogo.OK)
            {
                intResultado = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                intResultado = 1;
            }

            return intResultado;
        }
    }
```

And this is my Test:

```
[TestMethod]
        public void DialogoTest01()
        {
            //La clase que se va a probar, que en este caso tiene también el método que se tiene que hacer mock, de modo.
            Mock<IDialogoDummy> miDialogoDummyMock = new Mock<IDialogoDummy>();
            //Se indica que  cuando se llame al método dummy, con cualquier cadena tanto de mensaje como de caption, y con botones OKCancel y valor por
            //defecto Canceal, devuelva 0.
            miDialogoDummyMock.Setup(x => x.dummy(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>(), System.Windows.MessageBoxButton.OKCancel, System.Windows.MessageBoxResult.Cancel))
                .Returns(GTS.CMMS.Client.Dialogos.ResultadoDialogo.OK);

            DialogoDummyMethods misMetodos = new DialogoDummyMethods();
            int intResultado = misMetodos.getInt();
            Assert.AreEqual(0, intResultado, "Debería ser 0");
        }
```

The problem is taht the mock object is different to the object that is created in the method that I want to test, so when the method to test is executed, the messageBox is shown and I have to select an option.

How can I test my getInt method without the needed to select an option in the dialog?

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your SUT (class which you are testing) should depend on abstractions only. Don't instantiate dependencies inside class - that introduces dependency on concrete class, which you cannot mock. Inject dependencies via constructor/property/parameter dependency injection. That will allow you to provide mocked dependency implementation.

So, all together:

1) Depend on abstraction

```
public class DialogoDummyMethods
{
   private IDialogoDummy miGestor;

   public int getInt()
   {
        // DialogoDummyMethods knows nothing about IDialogoDummy implementation
        var resultado = miGestor.dummy(
             "OK es 0 y cancel es 1", "Test", 
             MessageBoxButton.OKCancel, MessageBoxResult.Cancel);

        return resultado == ResultadoDialogo.OK ? 0 : 1;
   }
}
```

2) Inject abstraction through constructor. Note - if only one method needs IDialogoDummy, then you can inject it as method parameter (in that case you don't need IDialogDummy as class field)

```
public DialogoDummyMethods(IDialogoDummy miGestor)
{
    this.miGestor = miGestor;
}
```

3) Mock dependency for unit-testing and inject mocked dependency to class which you are testing

```
var miDialogoDummyMock = new Mock<IDialogoDummy>();
// setup mock here
var misMetodos = new DialogoDummyMethods(miDialogoDummyMock.Object);
int intResultado = misMetodos.getInt();
Assert.AreEqual(0, intResultado, "Debería ser 0");
```

Comment: really I don't understand so much but I want to do the following. I have a view model that use the interface to show dialogs. So the view model need to create an object Dialogs to execute the method that show tue dialog. So when I want to test the view model, I have a method that create an object to show a dialog.

When I have to inject dependencies? In my test class or in my class with the method to test (view model)?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía you should inject dependecies to class which you are testing. I added step-by-step example

Comment: thanks for the detailed code. But I have a doubt, if I have a class with many methods that create many other objetct, does I need to have many properties in my class to inject? I meanm I have method01 that creates object01, method02 that creates method02... I need in my class properties object01, object02... etc? Because in this case I have to add code only for testing purpuses, I would like that the tested class only would have the code that I need to implement its functionality.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGarcía you can inject dependencies through method parameters, e.g. `void method01(object01 obj)` this way you will need to setup only `object01` for `method01` tests. If you have many dependencies in your class, then consider to redesign this class, maybe group some dependencies together. I have rule of thumb, that class usually should have 0-5 dependencies, the less - the better.